# Why does this string comparator not compile?

Tags: java, string, object, compare, comparator

This is the comparator I'm using:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class StringComparator implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(String obj1, String obj2) 
    {
        String delimeter = " ";
        String nameSplit1[] = obj1.split( delimeter );
        String nameSplit2[] = obj2.split( delimeter );

        return nameSplit1[1].compareTo(nameSplit2[1]);
    }
}
```

And this is the main file:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringCompare
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String delimeter = " ";

        stringList.add( "Seven Clocks" );
        stringList.add( "Twelve Beds" );
        stringList.add( "Eight Frogs" );


        Collections.sort( stringList, new StringComparator() );

        for ( String a : stringList )
        {
            System.out.println( a );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm basically trying to make a comparator so the collections.sort sorts according to the second word, not the first. But when I compile it, all I get is the StringComparator doesn't override the abstract method compare(Object, Object) error. Why is it giving me that error?...

Comment: You should use generics.

Comment: `compare(String, String)` doesn't override `compare(Object, Object)` which is the expected comparison method from a non-generic `Comparator`

Comment: The earlier rawtypes warning (assuming JDK 7) should give the game away. And an `@Override` would help.

Comment: Compiling makes change, if you are looking into one bytecode to compare with another bytecode better use the binary hex editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a comparator is a generic interface, and since you didn't define it to be a `Comparator<String>` it falls back on the most general definition, `Comparator<Object>` which means the parameters should be `Objects` and not `Strings`.

Change it to

```
public class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
```

and it should compile just fine.

Answer (score 6):

You left out the generic parameter from the Comparator declaration.

```
public class StringComparator implements Comparator<String>
//                                                     ^
//                you need this!                       |
// ----------------------------------------------------
```